# Agora.io web call decline

Tags: vue.js, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

How to close stream when remote user click on decline call.

```
    <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-danger"
    data-dismiss="modal"
    @click="declineCall"
    > Decline
    </button>

    declineCall() {
        // You can send a request to the caller to
        // alert them of rejected call
        this.incomingCall = false;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to close the remote users stream when the local user declines the call. In which case you'll have to use some mechanism to signal to the remote user to close the stream. For example, you can use the Agora RTM SDK to send a peer message to the remote user. On receiving this message the remote user can close the stream (`videoTrack.close()`).